# libvirtd bridged networking, what iface is right to set IP?

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

Accodring to the documentation assigning
of the IP addr it not mandatory for the *BR* interfaces.

I have 2 netwok configuration set on libvirtd hadware node.
Possibility one:

```
    1. eth0 172.16.33.55/24 (plain interface)
    2. br0 NO_IP_HERE with bridge_ports eth0
```

Possiblility two:

```
    1. eth0 NO_IP_HERE (plain interface)
    2. br0 172.16.33.55/24 with bridge_ports eth0
```

**which one is right?**

P.S. br0 will be used for the Guest nodes and free IPs from the 172.16.33.0/24 network will be assigned to the guests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are working fine.
But I always use the second one, eth0 bring network connectivity to the bridge, ip is set on the bridge, ip alias (if any) are set on the br0. I think it is the cleanest implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The IP address goes on the bridge interface (`br0` in your example).